# When recording on python with module sounddevice it records forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, python-sounddevice

I am currently making a python script that records for a specific amount of time that the user inputs, and then encrypts it with a password.

But when I start recording, it records forever, and I have to stop the script running to stop recording.

```
from sounddevice import rec, wait
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from getpass import getpass
from pyAesCrypt import encryptFile
from os import remove

fs = 44100  # Sample rate
while True:
    try:
        seconds = int(input("Enter how long to record for: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be an integer!")
    else:
        break
myrecording = rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)  # Record file
wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)
password = getpass("Enter password to encrypt file with: ")
encryptFile("output.wav", "output.ewf", password)
remove("output.wav")
print("Saved file as output.ewf")
```

is my code.

I have no idea why it stopped working.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using wait correctly? Looks like you should maybe be trying a conditional like if myrecording.wait(): then the rest of your code.
*edit, from here: https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/usage.html

Comment: Yes, sd.wait() should work

If the recording was already finished, this returns immediately; if not, **it waits and returns as soon as the recording is finished.**

Comment: I just ran your code w/ no errors. It seems to be running as expected. Have you managed to figure out what's wrong or is there something else happening? Did it work for a while then stop?

Comment: Yup. Once I imported pyAesCrypt and used it, it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the googlers out there, don't worry, it's fixed.

If you use PyCharm, then make sure to edit configuration and check **Emulate terminal in output console**

I think the problem was getpass.